# Qt application failed to run in a Pc without QT (windeployqt used)

Tags: windows, qt, dll

I have a QT 5.7 (VS 2013) app running properly on my PC (with QT installed), and I want to launch it in a PC without QT.

I have used 'windeployqt' to add all required libraries and folders to my binary path, and a lot of them have been added there.

I rename the 'QT' folder, to simulate another PC, and I launch the .exe file, but it fails:

```
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2013/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2013. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at D:/Projects/SpontaniaQML/Spontania-Desktop/Release. Trying fallback directory... The application MAY NOT work.
ModLoad: 00000000`0e8e0000 00000000`0e981000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`0e8e0000 00000000`0e8f7000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2013/translations\qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
(bfc.1ca4): WOW64 breakpoint - code 4000001f (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for D:\Projects\MyProject\Release\Qt5WebEngineCore.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for D:\Projects\MyProject\Release\Qt5WebEngineCore.dll - 
Qt5WebEngineCore!GetHandleVerifier+0x22c71:
579c8d61 cc              int     3
```

Is it an ICU problem? I have not found any of these libraries in my QT path to add to my binary folder...

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem. In my PATH variable I had references to QT 5.5, not to QT 5.7. Updated that, the app runs properly